# pygazebo: How do I get the current joint angle

Tags: python

I would like to get the current joint angle of a joint using pygazebo. I can allready set the force on a joint using this: [Controlling a joint](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8763/pygazebo-python-gazebo-interface/)
And now i wanna make an PID controller.

I did this:

```
import pygazebo
import pygazebo.msg.joint_cmd_pb2
from pygazebo.msg.gz_string_pb2 import GzString

import trollius
from trollius import From

@trollius.coroutine


def callback(data):
    message = pygazebo.msg.gz_string_pb2.GzString.FromString(data)
    print('Received message:', message.data)


manager = pygazebo.Manager(('localhost', 11345))
manager.subscribe('/gazebo/default/my_robot/joint',
                  'gazebo.msgs.GzString',
                  callback)
```

But it gives me an AssertionError: assert self._local_ready.is_set(). I do not undestand what i should put in the manager.subscribe field. I think this is where my error is.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through the code in pygazebo.py and traced the calls backwards. The manager creates a couple of Connection objects, a master and a server. I guess it uses the master connection to connect to the gazebo server, and the server connection to bind to a port of it's own to receive incoming requests.

As far as I can see you will need to call.

```
manager.start()
```

Before you call the subscribe method. This will make the manager connect to the gazebo server and bind to a local port to receive input data.

I hope it helps.